# Qt-5.1 | QNetworkAccessManager - set active ftp mode

Tags: qt, ftp

I am writing a simple program in Qt-5.1 to upload a file into my remote ftp server.

Due to my network configuration, I can't use the **passive** mode. So, I need to use **active** mode.

By default `QNetworkAccessManager` is using passive mode to transfer data. How can I setup it to use active mode.

```
QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QString file = "file.txt";
QUrl url("ftp://anonymous:@127.0.0.1:21/" + name);
QFile *localPath = new QFile("c:\\" + name);

connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finished(QNetworkReply*)));

QNetworkReply *reply = manager.put(QNetworkRequest(url), localPath);
```

PS: As for using `Qftp`, they said:

```
"However, for new applications, it is recommended to use QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply, as those classes possess a simpler, yet more powerful API."
```

So, I am trying to avoid this solution.

Comment: I don't think there's a way. Please open a bug report; you'd need a custom QNetworkRequest attribute for setting active or passive mode. In the meanwhile, use QFtp.